# Sum up numbers and change the unknown variable C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So for a starting code I'm trying to make a clicked game and I'm stuck. I've assigned a variable int Cookies = 0 and I want it so when I click a button (button1_Click) it add up to 1 (so 0+1 = 1) then assigns the int Cookies = 0 to int Cookies to = 1 and so on...

```
    namespace CookieClicker
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int Cookies = 0;
            int End = Cookies + 1;
            label1.Text = "Cookies: " + End;
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: what's your question..? also you are aware the `Label.Text` property is of type string so in order for the `label1.Text = "Cookies: " + End;` you need to convert `End` to a string using `.ToString()` or `Convert.ToString()` method

Comment: I think problem is that after first click it says "Cookies: 1" forever.

Comment: you need to declare the Incremented variables outside of the Click Event.. also read the following [Variable and Method Scope in Microsoft .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx) this will save you a lot of head scratching as you become more proficient in coding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As first you need to store count of cookies outside of method called on button click.

```
int cookies = 0;
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cookies++; // adds one cookie on each click
    label1.Text = string.Format("Cookies: {0}", cookies);
}
```

As second I would recommend you start with some good tutorial to catch basics of C#. (Like this one for example: http://visualcsharptutorials.com/windows-forms/)

Comment: Thanks :) Also thank you for the link, I'll check it out

Comment: In fact they do. Return in void terminates method body execution without returning value but it's true that in this case it was redundant.